# Linux kernel not upgraded from 3.2.x to 3.5.x after Ubuntu upgrade from 12.04 LTS to 12.10 (through 12.10 beta)

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 12.10, beta

I had upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 beta from 12.04 LTS. I kept updating every recommended update suggested by Software Updater. All updates were successful.

Yesterday, 12.10 stable is formally released and my software updater has applied all updates without any error/warning. But looks like my Ubuntu has been not fully upgraded to 12.10. For example the Linux kernel is still in 3.2.x and not upgraded to 3.5.0. (Screens attached).

PS: Spam prevention mechanism not allowing to attach images. Just adding the commands:

```
08:21:25-~] lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:    12.10
Codename:   quantal

08:49:56-~] uname -a
Linux NOD-AF1-LO-J005 3.2.0-25-generic-pae #40-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 22:11:24 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

08:49:59-~]
```

Answer (score 1):

Could find the exact reason why the dist-upgrade did not upgraded Linux kernel from 3.2.x to 3.5.x

I installed the Linux kernel 3.5.18 manually through Synaptic Package manager.

```
12:37:57-~] uname -a
Linux NOD-AF1-LO-J005 3.5.0-18-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 19 10:27:31 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
12:38:00-~]
```